# sass: equality operators have inconsistent behavior, is it a bug?

Tags: function, sass, operator-keyword, equality

Check this function

```
@function mathOperation($number, $type) {
@if $type == sum or $type == rest {
    @return true
} @else {
        @return false
    }
}
@debug mathOperation(5, sum);
@debug mathOperation(5, rest);
@debug mathOperation(5, division);
```

And just as expected the result is this

DEBUG: true

DEBUG: true

DEBUG: false

But if we modify the equality operator in this function to !=

```
@function mathOperation2($number, $type) {
    @if $type != sum or $type != rest {
        @return true
    } @else {
        @return false
    }
}

@debug mathOperation2(5, sum);
@debug mathOperation2(5, rest);
@debug mathOperation2(5, division);
```

the results become odd

DEBUG: true

DEBUG: true

DEBUG: true

am I missing something? is this behavior a bug ? I am compiling using grunt-sass 2.1.0

Comment: The condition in the second example will always be true, because $type cannot be two values at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second example the code should be:

```
@function mathOperation2($number, $type) {
    @if $type != sum and $type != rest {
        @return true
    } @else {
        @return false
    }
}
```

The `or` in the `if` statement means that the condition will be accepted if one of the two conditions is true. You should use `and` so the condition will be tru if both of the statements are true.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answers, I didn't sleep for the last 5 days (son at hospital) I solved it with a map:

```
@function map-select-key($map, $key, $direction) {
    $direction-map: (previous: -1, next: 1);
    @if map-has-key($direction-map, $direction) == false {
        @warn '#{$direction} is not an accepted parameter, the only 
parameters accepted for $direction are "#{map-keys($direction-map)}"';
    @return null;
} @else if (map-index-from-key($map, $key) == 1) and ($direction == previous) or (map-index-from-key($map, $key) == length($map)) and ($direction == next) {
    @warn 'it is not possible to select the #{$direction} item: #{$key} is the #{if($direction == previous, first, last)} element on the map #{$map}';
    @return null;
} @else {
    @return map-key-from-index($map, map-index-from-key($map, $key) + map-get($direction-map, $direction));
    }
}
```